# Why my javascript code in svelte doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

My problem with svelte occurred after I wrote some html, then added some JavaScript to one Svelte page :

```
import {validate} from "+page.svelte";

<form>
  <label for="username">Kullanıcı Adı:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
  <label for="password">Şifre:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Giriş Yap" onclick="validate()">
</form>

<script type="text" src="page.svelte">
  function validate() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (username === "kullaniciadi" && password === "sifre") {
      alert("Giriş başarılı!");
      window.location.href = "ana_sayfa.html";
    } else {
      alert("Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış. Lütfen tekrar deneyin.");
    }
  }
  </script>
```

But when I launch it the JavaScript doesn't work.

I checked my code with developer settings in chrome and I saw different code just the html is the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head>
    <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
        <div style="display: contents">
<form><label for="username">Kullanıcı Adı:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
  <label for="password">Şifre:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Giriş Yap" onclick="validate()">
</form>
            <script>
                {
                    __sveltekit_dev = {
                        env: {},
                        base: new URL(".", location).pathname.slice(0, -1),
                        element: document.currentScript.parentElement
                    };

                    const data = [null,null];

                    Promise.all([
                        import("/@fs/C:/Users/sekto/OneDrive/Masaüstü/Svelte-dev/myapp/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/client/start.js"),
                        import("./C:\\Users\\sekto\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\Svelte-dev\\myapp\\.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js")
                    ]).then(([kit, app]) => {
                        kit.start(app, __sveltekit_dev.element, {
                            node_ids: [0, 2],
                            data,
                            form: null,
                            error: null
                        });
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error just only in developer settings like this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((dizin):28:63)
> onclick @ (dizin):28

Comment: With Svelte it's `on:eventname` https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-on-eventname - for internal navigation there's `goto()` https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto

Comment: Try to rephrase your question so that it is useful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't read the docs for how to call functions in Svelte. Also, don't bother with manual DOM manipulation, you don't need any of that in Svelte. Svelte isn't just HTML, there are syntactic differences. The JS is different on the client(in your dev tools) because it's transpiled on rollup. Also stop using JavaScript and start using TypeScript.
I recommend giving [Svelte Examples](https://svelte.dev/examples/hello-world) a read.

```
     <script lang="ts">
         let username = ""
         let password = ""
         function validate() {
             if (username === "kullaniciadi" && password === "sifre") {
                alert("Giriş başarılı!");
                window.location.href = "ana_sayfa.html";
             } else {
                 alert("Kullanıcı adı veya şifre yanlış. Lütfen tekrar deneyin.");
             }
         }
     </script>

     <form>
         <label for="username">Kullanıcı Adı:</label>
         <input bind:value={username} type="text" id="username" name="username"><be><be>
         <label for="password">Şifre:</label>
         <input bind:value={password} type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><be>
         <input type="button" value="Giriş Yap" on:click={validate}>
    </form>
```